# TypeError: _this.props.onCreate is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Help me out, I am new to React and Javascript

Getting this error:"**TypeError: _this.props.onCreate is not a function**" although the function has been passed in the props and has been bound.

Here is my current code in react.

```
UserCreate.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserCreate extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: ''
    };
}

handleChange = email => event => {
    this.setState(
        {
            [email]: event.target.value,
        }
    )
}

handleCreate = () => {
    console.log('create', this.state.email);
    this.props.onCreate({'email': this.state.email});
}

render() {
    let userData = this.props.user && this.props.user.email;
    return (
       <div>
         <h3> New User Form </h3>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange('email')} placeholder="Email"/>
        <button onClick={this.handleCreate}>Create</button>
      </div>
    );
}
}

export default UserCreate;

    App.js
    const USerCreateWithData = compose(
  graphql(UserCreateMutation, {
    props: (props) => ({
      onCreate: (user) => {
        props.mutate({
          variables: { ...user },
          optimisticResponse: () => ({ createUser: { ...user, __typename: 'User'}})
        })
      }

    }  
    ),
    options: {
      update: (dataProxy, { data: { createUser }}) => {

      }
    }
  })
)(UserCreate);

UserCreateMutation
export default gql`
mutation UserCreateMutation($email: String!){
    createUser(
        email: $email
    ) {
        __typename
        id
        email
    }
}
`;
```

What I am doing wrong in here? I have tried every solutions that I have seen on google, stackoverflow but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Isn't `onCreate` an event?

Comment: I guess it is, i'm not entirely familiar with following a tutorial

Comment: add the code snippet from the file which imports and use this component

Comment: @AnshulSahni I have added further code.